# Do manifolds have the homotopy type of finite-dimensional CW-complexes?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, betti-numbers

It is well know that a topological manifold $M$ is homotopy equivalent to a CW-complex $X$. In addition, if $M$ is compact, one even has $M \simeq X$ for some *finite* CW-complex.

In a [Mathoverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201944/topological-n-manifolds-have-the-homotopy-type-of-n-dimensional-cw-complexes), it was discussed if one can take an $n$-dimensional CW-complex $X$ if $M$ is of dimension $n$. However, I have not found a clear reference in this thread, but I think most people believe it to be true.

**My question** is: Can we at least say for sure (with a good reference/reason) that we can find a *finite dimensional* CW-complex $X$ with $M \simeq X$ for every topological manifold $M$?

It seems as if Milnor in [On spaces having the homotopy type of a CW-complex](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjZ-bCc1uTQAhXrCsAKHf8FDuwQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maths.ed.ac.uk%2F~aar%2Fpapers%2Fmilnorcw.pdf&usg=AFQjCNECvj7HyMXWZhNz39zsANnOBoohmA) proves this claim, because the manifold gets embedded into a finite dimensional simplicial complex. But I have some trouble reading this article. Is there a better reference or resource for this fact? It seems quite useful to me.

Comment: If you just want an (unreadable) reference, you can argue as follows. 1. Kirby and Siebenmann proved (in their book) that every topological $n$-manifold  (assuming $n\ne 4$) $M$ has a handle decomposition, in particular, it is homotopy-equivalent to an $n$-dimensional CW complex. To deal with the case $n=4$, replace $M$ with $M\times [0,1]$ and then apply Kirby-Siebenmann. As for a readable reference, I am not sure, will think about one.

Comment: Take a look at the book Lundell and Weingram "The Topology of CW-Complexes", it might be better than Milnor's exposition.